# Won't save an edit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've added an boolean "ChangedPassword" to my database. I have to force the users to change their passwords at their first login.

After they have changed their password, the boolean has to change to true. It's working, but it won't save it.

My code:

```
        // POST: /Manage/ChangePassword
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ChangePassword(ChangePasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        var result = await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            }
            SidewindContext db = new SidewindContext();

            if (user.ChangedPassword == false)
            {
                user.ChangedPassword = true;
            }
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Message = ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess });
        }
        AddErrors(result);
        return View(model);
    }
```

I'm not sure if I need db.SaveChanges but it's not working with or without. 
Any idea? Let me know.

Comment: `user` is not in the same context as `db`.

Comment: Either find the `user` using the `SidewindContext` itself without using the `UserManager` and assigne `true` to `ChangedPassword` or create a method within the user manager which assigns `true` to `ChangedPassword` which uses the context that `UserManager` is using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `Attach` the object within your newly created `DbContext` in order for EntityFramework to start tracking the changes of the object. Without it, your newly created context knows **nothing** about the changes to the `user` object.

```
SidewindContext db = new SidewindContext();

db.Attach(user);

if (user.ChangedPassword == false)
{
    user.ChangedPassword = true;
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This might be a dumb question to ask but my db won't recognize Attach? I've tried multiple contextes but none found the method Attach

Comment: @DannyBrouwer Weird, what version of EntityFramework are you using? It should be in `System.Data.Objects`, you may need a `using` directive (see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.attach%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @DannyBrouwer Did you try adding the `using` directive?

Comment: I've figured it out! I had to use 'SidewindContext db = this.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<SidewindContext>();' to get the **attach** method. Thank you for answering!

Comment: @DannyBrouwer No probems, glad you got it sorted. If this was the correct answer, hit the "tick" icon to mark it as correct. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Would db.tableName.Attach(entity) help?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try this

```
db.Entry(user).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```